# What is wrong here to rotate, move, draw and zoom?

Tags: vb.net, rotation, zooming, move

```
' details of bitmap
Dim bm As New Bitmap(1000, 1000)
Dim graph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
'when mouse down on pic draw values
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
  Dim rad As Double
  Dim angle As Integer
  rad = angle * System.Math.PI / 180
  'equations for rotate lines

  Dim x As Integer = System.Math.Sin(rad) - System.Math.Cos(rad)
  Dim y As Integer = System.Math.Sin(rad) + System.Math.Cos(rad)
  Dim z As Integer = System.Math.Cos(rad) + System.Math.Sin(rad)

  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 150 + e.X, 210 + e.Y, y + 150 - e.X, (x) + 210 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 160 + e.X, 220 + e.Y, (y) + 160 - e.X, (x) + 220 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 170 + e.X, 230 + e.Y, y + 170 - e.X, (x) + 230 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 180 + e.X, 240 + e.Y, (y) + 180 - e.X, (x) + 240 - e.Y)

  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 210 + e.X, 150 + e.Y, y + 210 - e.X, (x) + 150 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 220 + e.X, 160 + e.Y, (y) + 220 - e.X, (x) + 160 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 230 + e.X, 170 + e.Y, y + 230 - e.X, (x) + 170 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 240 + e.X, 180 + e.Y, (y) + 240 - e.X, (x) + 180 - e.Y)

  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), 210 + e.X, 150 + e.Y, 150 + e.X, 210 + e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), 220 + e.X, 160 + e.Y, 160 + e.X, 220 + e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), 230 + e.X, 170 + e.Y, 170 + e.X, 230 + e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), 240 + e.X, 180 + e.Y, 180 + e.X, 240 + e.Y)

  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), y + 210 - e.X, (x) + 150 - e.Y, y + 150 - e.X, (x) + 210 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), (y) + 220 - e.X, (x) + 160 - e.Y, (y) + 160 - e.X, (x) + 220 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), y + 230 - e.X, (x) + 170 - e.Y, y + 170 - e.X, (x) + 230 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), (y) + 240 - e.X, (x) + 180 - e.Y, (y) + 180 - e.X, (x) + 240 - e.Y)

  PictureBox1.Image = bm
End Sub
```

When mouse move rotate lines but here my asking want to make it didnt stretch and drawing object and rotate:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
  PictureBox1.Refresh()
  Dim graph As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
  Dim rad As Double
  Dim angle As Integer
  rad = angle * System.Math.PI / 180

  Dim x As Integer = System.Math.Sin(rad) - System.Math.Cos(rad)
  Dim y As Integer = System.Math.Sin(rad) + System.Math.Cos(rad)
  Dim z As Integer = System.Math.Cos(rad) + System.Math.Sin(rad)

  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), e.X, e.Y, x + 200 - e.X, (y) + 400 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Red, 1), e.X, e.Y, (y) + 400 - e.X, (z) + 200 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Blue, 1), e.X, e.Y, z + 400 + e.X, x + 200 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 150 + e.X, 210 + e.Y, y + 150 - e.X, (x) + 210 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 160 + e.X, 220 + e.Y, (y) + 160 - e.X, (x) + 220 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 170 + e.X, 230 + e.Y, y + 170 - e.X, (x) + 230 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 180 + e.X, 240 + e.Y, (y) + 180 - e.X, (x) + 240 - e.Y)

  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 210 + e.X, 150 + e.Y, y + 210 - e.X, (x) + 150 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 220 + e.X, 160 + e.Y, (y) + 220 - e.X, (x) + 160 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 230 + e.X, 170 + e.Y, y + 230 - e.X, (x) + 170 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 240 + e.X, 180 + e.Y, (y) + 240 - e.X, (x) + 180 - e.Y)

  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), 210 + e.X, 150 + e.Y, 150 + e.X, 210 + e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), 220 + e.X, 160 + e.Y, 160 + e.X, 220 + e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), 230 + e.X, 170 + e.Y, 170 + e.X, 230 + e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), 240 + e.X, 180 + e.Y, 180 + e.X, 240 + e.Y)

  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), y + 210 - e.X, (x) + 150 - e.Y, y + 150 - e.X, (x) + 210 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), (y) + 220 - e.X, (x) + 160 - e.Y, (y) + 160 - e.X, (x) + 220 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), y + 230 - e.X, (x) + 170 - e.Y, y + 170 - e.X, (x) + 230 - e.Y)
  graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Green, 1), (y) + 240 - e.X, (x) + 180 - e.Y, (y) + 180 - e.X, (x) + 240 - e.Y)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have tagged your question as VB, but I'm not sure if that's correct. So could you optionally [`edit the post`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20746140/edit) and use a proper tag ? Anyway, your post doesn't make much sense. You should describe what is wrong in details. What is the expected result and what you actually see. Thanks!

Comment: @TLama: Yep, looks like VB.NET. A wall of text in VB.NET.

Comment: @Neolisk, phew :-) I hope I didn't break the formatting so much...

Comment: The formula for Z is the same as Y, that seems odd. Sin and Cos returns a value from 0 to 1. When you add "x + 200" you aren't doing much, you should multiply instead "x * 200". I would suggest you look and learn the formulas correct first. And only draw one line to begin with, make sure one thing works before doing the other.

Comment: thx for all i know that  formula is not correct  but i refer to make axis move with 3d body more explain i want to draw in 3d but when i change value didnt going with me because need to renew value in axis and body how can i make that to rotate and move when i drawing saving value to note and reback value to rotate how can i make that

Answer (score 1):

The approach of copy/pasting your code is wrong.

```
graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 150 + e.X, 210 + e.Y, y + 150 - e.X, (x) + 210 - e.Y)
graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 160 + e.X, 220 + e.Y, (y) + 160 - e.X, (x) + 220 - e.Y)
graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 170 + e.X, 230 + e.Y, y + 170 - e.X, (x) + 230 - e.Y)
graph.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Orange, 1), 180 + e.X, 240 + e.Y, (y) + 180 - e.X, (x) + 240 - e.Y)
```

95% of programming is about reading code. Therefore, when you write code, you need to make sure you've written as little as possible, so that you spend less time reading it later, or someone else would.

If you look at your wall of code #1, you can see that all sequences start with numbers 150 or 210. And then there is a +10 increment. Also, there is no point in taking `y` and `x` in square brackets. Using the above, your code can be rewritten:

```
Sub DrawLines(g As Graphics, color As Color, offsetX As Integer, offsetY As Integer) 
  For i As Integer = 0 to 3
    Dim leftShift As Integer = offsetX + i*10
    Dim topShift As Integer = offsetY + i*10
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(color, 1),
               leftShift + e.X, topShift + e.Y,
               y + leftShift - e.X, x + topShift - e.Y)     
  Next
End Sub
```

Then these 4 and other 4 similar lines become this:

```
DrawLines(graph, Color.Orange, 150, 210)
DrawLines(graph, Color.Orange, 210, 150)
```

Now, isn't that more readable? Isn't it easier to spot a problem in these two lines, rather than the other 8? Please make sure, before you start digging into a problem, nothing else is on your "table" that could slow you down. This principle is called [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). In this case, code quality is slowing you down in finding the solution. When we look at two similar code pieces, we are trying to figure out the similarities (naturally). The more differences - the less time is spent on looking at code. Take your time to refactor in a way similar to above, and post back when you are done.

Comment: i worte this code but axis x,y,z not good for health ,so i want to move this shap no worng in this code but i mean change and add for more move shap and rotate it because im not advanced in vb.net

Comment: @user3129855: That code is not good for health, yes... :) Seriously though, it's not clear what you are asking there. So I was just trying to set you on the right path. The thing is if you don't know how to ask and you have a 100 lines of code, we probably won't be able to help you (too much mental strain, and we don't know if that's what you meant). On the other hand, if you don't know how to ask, but only have 5 lines code, we sometimes can infer the question from the code you have, and we would still help you. Adding screenshots would help too, if you have some to share.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/z886.png/

Comment: @ihab: I think you need to look into DirectX, doing everything manually would be lots of pain. See this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168829/Basic-Directx-Transformation-with-VB-NET Use google to get more examples.

Comment: thx neolisk but i didnt like to use directx ,so thx very much for ur answring i read it before,if i found any problem i will asking you again